# Как сделать, чтобы в окно консоли  вмещалось больше строк?

Tags: delphi

Как сделать, чтобы в окно консоли  вмещалось больше строк?

Comment: Растянуть окно мышью.

Comment: Вы меня не поняли. Допустим, я вывожу в консоль с каждой новой строчки номер строчки до 1000. Дояйдя до 1000, я  прокручиваю консоль до самого верха, где вместо ожидаемой единицы вижу 765. А как мне увеличить это пространство?

Comment: @ололо, каков вопрос - таков ответ.  Правильно сами же ответили.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  f.X:=1200;
  f.Y:=1200;
  SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),f);
```